# NSD Zone file wrong resolution

Tags: ubuntu, dns

I've set up NSD with the following zone file:

```
$ORIGIN     ldom. ; my "Local DOMain"
@   IN      SOA         lserver         root.lserver (
                                        44         ;serial
                                        7200       ;refresh
                                        600        ;retry
                                        3600000    ;expire
                                        1200 )     ;minimum

@                   IN  NS              192.168.1.64      ; authority
ldom.               IN  A               192.168.1.64
```

and no matter where on the LAN I ping/dig it, I get the following output which is obviously wrong:

Ping:

```
[user@laptop ~]$ ping ldom
PING ldom (127.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from localhost.localdomain (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.016 ms
64 bytes from localhost.localdomain (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.027 ms
64 bytes from localhost.localdomain (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.037 ms
^C
--- ldom ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 1998ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.016/0.026/0.037/0.010 ms
[user@laptop ~]$
```

Dig:

```
[user@laptop ~]$ dig ldom

; <<>> DiG 9.9.2-P2 <<>> ldom
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 23335
;; flags: qr aa rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 1
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;ldom.                                IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
ldom.                 3600    IN      A       127.0.0.1

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
ldom.                 3600    IN      NS      localhost.ldom.

;; Query time: 1 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.1.64#53(192.168.1.64)
;; WHEN: Wed Apr  2 12:04:33 2014
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 75

[user@laptop ~]$
```

the `laptop` is "192.168.1.65" (DHCP) and the NSD server is "192.168.1.64" and the switch is the DSL router (192.168.1.1) with DNS1=192.168.1.64 and DNS2=ISP's

Why am I getting 127.0.0.1? I want "192.168.1.64"! What part am I doing wrong?

I've tried changing the "lserver" in SOA with 192.168.1.64 but there's no difference. Any change I tried results in the exact same response, even changing the NS and A record destinations.

Answer (score 0):

THE ANSWER:

The database needed an update **(a new question would be: Why manually?)**:

```
#zonec -v
zonec: reading zone "ldom".
zonec: processed 3 RRs in "ldom".

zonec: done with no errors.
#service nsd3 restart ; UBUNTU
```

AND EVERYTHING IS FINE!

GOOD LUCK FELLAS!